# Distinguishing Player Categories SQL

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to distinguish  players based on their activity for example if someone has only played 'lottery' they are a 'lottery_player', if someone has played lottery, bingo and slots but over 50% time spent playing lottery then they are 'lottery_mainly' player. However when I write my query it is not able to see the difference and categorise correctly.

```
with player_activity as ( 
select
PLAYER_ID,  
sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Lottery' then 1 else 0 end) as lotto_bets,
sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Sportsbook' then 1 else 0 end) as Sportsbook_bets,  
sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Scratchcard' then 1 else 0 end) as Scratchcard_bets,
sum(case when GENRE_ID  in ('Instant games', 'Games') then 1 else 0 end) as Slot_bets,
sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Bingo' then 1 else 0 end) as Bingo_bets,
sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Bundles' then 1 else 0 end) as Bundle_bets,
lotto_bets +Sportsbook_bets + Scratchcard_bets + Slot_bets + Bingo_bets + Bundle_bets  as total_bets,
lotto_bets/nullif(total_bets,0) *100 as lotto_percentage,
Sportsbook_bets/nullif(total_bets,0) *100 as sportsbook_percentage,
Scratchcard_bets/ nullif(total_bets,0) * 100 as scratchcard_percentage,
Slot_bets/ nullif(total_bets,0) * 100 AS slots_percentage,
Bingo_bets/ nullif(total_bets,0) * 100 AS Bingo_percentage,
Bundle_bets/ nullif(total_bets,0) * 100 AS Bundle_percentage, 
case
     when  lotto_percentage >50  then 'lotto_mainly'
     when  lotto_bets > '0' AND lotto_percentage = '100.000000' then 'lotto_only'
     end as favoured_product

FROM lottoprod_dw.TRANSACTION_LINES
GROUP BY 1)
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: HI @jarlh I have removed some code. Does this now help?

Comment: You want take ``time spent playing`` and take ``count playing``. Can you count ``time spent`` by ``genre_id``?

Comment: I Want to be able to categorise players based on those who have only played one product for example Lottery and people who have played mainly lottery e..g over 50% of the time but played other products also.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your query, you are trying to use computed columns and their results in the same query. You will probably need to write get bets, then totals, then the percentage in different sections of your cte. Like this:
With totals as (select bets), (select totals), (select percentages), (select favourable)

This is untested code based off your question's code.

```
WITH PlayerBets AS 
(
    SELECT
            PLAYER_ID,  
            sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Lottery' then 1 else 0 end) as lotto_bets,
            sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Sportsbook' then 1 else 0 end) as Sportsbook_bets,  
            sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Scratchcard' then 1 else 0 end) as Scratchcard_bets,
            sum(case when GENRE_ID  in ('Instant games', 'Games') then 1 else 0 end) as Slot_bets,
            sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Bingo' then 1 else 0 end) as Bingo_bets,
            sum(case when GENRE_ID  ='Bundles' then 1 else 0 end) as Bundle_bets
    FROM lottoprod_dw.TRANSACTION_LINES
)
,PlayerBetTotals AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,nullif(lotto_bets + Sportsbook_bets + Scratchcard_bets + Slot_bets + Bingo_bets + Bundle_bets, 0) AS total_bets
    FROM PlayerBets
)
,PlayerActivitiy AS
(
    SELECT *
        ,lotto_bets / total_bets * 100 AS lotto_percentage
        ,Sportsbook_bets / total_bets * 100 AS sportsbook_percentage
        ,Scratchcard_bets / total_bets * 100 AS scratchcard_percentage
        ,Slot_bets / total_bets * 100 AS slots_percentage
        ,Bingo_bets / total_bets * 100 AS Bingo_percentage
        ,Bundle_bets / total_bets * 100 AS Bundle_percentage
    FROM PlayerBetTotals
)
SELECT *
    ,CASE 
    WHEN lotto_percentage > 50
        THEN 'lotto_mainly'
    WHEN lotto_bets > '0'
        AND lotto_percentage = '100.000000'
        THEN 'lotto_only'
    END AS favoured_product
FROM PlayerActivity
```

Comment: @Dr.J- Thank you for your advice. I will try compartmentalising each segment.

Comment: I updated my answer with a code example that should help visualize how you would aggregate things, then use them in subsequent subqueries.